# Recovery key set by my "company, school, or institution" on private laptop

Tags: macos, filevault, recovery

I want to enable FileVault encryption but in the dialog I encounter this message:

> A recovery key has been set by your company, school, or institution.

I don't have my laptop set up by a company, school or institution because this is my private laptop.

This dialog may be related to some profile-files I have recently installed for university in order to get the VPN to work. How can I reset this so that I can use my own recovery key?

I am using macOS 10.13.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The message disappeared after moving the files `/Library/Keychains/FileVaultMaster.cer` and `/Library/Keychains/FileVaultMaster.keychain` to a different directory.

Comment: Can I just delete them though?

Comment: I only moved them so that I could restore them if needed. I would not delete master keys.

Comment: Ok. I did actually delete them and then I regenerated the key, and wrote it down, so I actually now KNOW the keys. I'm pretty sure this is the right way to use them, but, I'm not 100 percent sure, admittedly.

Answer (score 12):

[This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3811692) Apple discussion says:

> After a couple of exchanges with our engineering team they have recommended two things you may try.
>
> The first solution is as follows:
>
> - Disable FileVault
> - In the system directory, go to `/Library/Keychains`
> - Move the files `FileVaultMaster.keychain` and `FileVaultMaster.cer` to the Trash.
>   Deleting the files should then allow you to enable FileVault on the system and provide a recovery key. Refer to article http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5077 if you have questions regarding the location of the files.
>
> Second solution:
>
> Performing an erase and reinstall of the computer system will reset the master password and allow you to encrypt the drive again.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open Terminal application
2. Enter and press return:

   ```
   sudo fdesetup removerecovery -institutional
   ```
3. Enter the administrator password
4. Enter and press return:

   ```
   sudo fdesetup changerecovery -personal
   ```
5. Enter the administrator password
6. A recovery key is generated.

Answer (score 2):

This message appears when enabling FileVault after transferring a disk image of a FileVault-encrypted machine to a new machine.

In this case, accepting the message seems to preserve the old machine's recovery key.

Comment: I did not do that. I had the volume encrypted some while ago, but disabled it after having problems with the login screen.

Comment: Ah, so possibly the key was still there from that encryption pass.